# Creating custom control and associate to the HTML element

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers

I use OpenLayers 6.
I try to create custom geolocation control which is fired on click.
The HTML buttons located outside of the map.

Here definition of the button location button outside of the map:

```
   <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="centered-butons">
    <div data-role="controlgroup" id="footerControls" data-type="horizontal" style="text-align: center" data-theme="b">

        <a href="#streetsearchpage" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-icon="search" data-transition="none">Search</a>
        <a href="#" id="locate" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-icon="location" data-transition="none">Location</a>
    </div>
   </div>
```

And here how I try to create custom control:

```
 var LocateControl = /*@__PURE__*/(function (Control) {
    function LocateControl(opt_options) {

        var target = document.querySelector('#locate');

        Control.call(this, {
            //element: element
            target: target
        });

        element.addEventListener('click', this.handleLocateTo.bind(this), false);
    }

    //some logic

    return LocateControl;
}(ol.control.Control));
```

I don't want to create dynamically button and use **element property** inside call function 
instead, I want to use a button that already exists (id="locate").

So I tried the code above and I get this error:

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined
```

Is there any way to associate custom control with existed button outside of the map(in my case id="locate")?

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is when creating the control on the `call` method. You are setting the target but, in your case, you don't need that because you are not going to place anything there. Also, you might have an error If you don't provide a `Node` in element, it can work but you might see it in the console.

Here I took the custom control OL example and modified it so it use an external button.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.1.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
   #a { display: none; }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.1.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <title>Custom Control</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Reset Rotation:
      <button id="b">N</button>
    </div>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var RotateNorthControl = /*@__PURE__*/(function (Control) {
      function RotateNorthControl(opt_options) {
        var options = opt_options || {};
        var button = document.getElementById('b');
        Control.call(this, {
          element: document.createElement('div'),
          target: options.target
        });
        button.addEventListener('click', this.handleRotateNorth.bind(this), false);
      }
      if ( Control ) RotateNorthControl.__proto__ = Control;
      RotateNorthControl.prototype = Object.create( Control && Control.prototype );
      RotateNorthControl.prototype.constructor = RotateNorthControl;
      RotateNorthControl.prototype.handleRotateNorth = function handleRotateNorth () {
        this.getMap().getView().setRotation(0);
      };

      return RotateNorthControl;
    }(ol.control.Control));
    var map = new ol.Map({
      controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
        new RotateNorthControl()
      ]),
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
      ],
      target: 'map',
      view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 3,
        rotation: 1
      })
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*Update*

Maybe the real answer to your problem is that you don't need a custom control in your case. The thing, is that basically you can solve your problem by binding the `onclick` event of the button to some function that do what you want. I might not be seeing the whole picture, though.

The target property let you bind the control to an element outside the map control. While the element property is the container of the custom control.

So basically, in the first solution, I cheated by giving them empty nodes (I admit is probably not the best solution).

Check this new example that I made for you with cases of all this thing,

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.1.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
   #ovmap { height: 150px; margin-top: 20px;}
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.1.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <title>Controls</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row mt-2">
        <div class="col">
          <h3>Button</h3>
          <button id="b" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
          onclick="handleRotateNorth()">N</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <h3>OverviewMap</h3>
          <div id="ovmap"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <h3>Scaleline</h3>
          <div id="scale"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row mt-2">
        <div id="map" class="map"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var source = new ol.source.OSM();
    var overviewMapControl = new ol.control.OverviewMap({
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: source
        })
      ],
      target: document.getElementById('ovmap'),
      collapsed: false
    });
    var scalelineControl = new ol.control.ScaleLine({
      target: document.getElementById('scale')
    });
    var map = new ol.Map({
      controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
        overviewMapControl,
        scalelineControl
      ]),
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: source
        })
      ],
      target: 'map',
      view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 3,
        rotation: 1
      })
    });
    function handleRotateNorth () {
        map.getView().setRotation(0);
    };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. Could you please explain regarding this block:
      Control.call(this, {
          element: document.createElement('div'),
          target: options.target
        });
it dosent have any usage in you example.Can it be removed?